# Gradle idea plugin excluded transitive dependency from other sub-project not excluded

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, dependency-management

I have a gradle project with the following dependency structure:

```
root
+--- module1
|    \--- 'some:dependency:1.0' (Maven dependency)
|         \--- 'some:transitive:2.1' (transitive dep)
\--- module2
     +--- module1
     +--- exclude 'some:transitive:2.1'
     \--- 'some:other:1.0'
          \--- 'other:transitive:1.1'
```

Basically `module2` excludes the dependency `some:transitive:2.1` (which is transitive for `module1`). This is because it conflicts at runtime with `other:transitive:1.1` (I can provide the exact libraries I'm talking about but it's irrelevant to my question) and the group id and artifact id are different so it must be manually excluded:

```
configurations.all {
  exclude group: 'some', module: 'transitive', version: '2.1'
}
```

The dependency is correctly excluded (I can tell by executing the `dependencyInsight` task). And if I create a test in `module2` that uses code from `some:other:1.0` that will trigger the runtime conflict, it gets run successfully using Gradle because the jar is excluded:

```
gradle :module2:test -Dtest.single=SomeTest
```

Now I am using IntelliJ 12 (so poor Gradle integration) and I generate the .ipr and .iml files using the Gradle `idea` plugin. Everything works pretty well.

However, if I run `SomeTest` from the IDE, I will get the runtime conflict triggered by the clash mentioned above. Looking at the IDE test classpath I see that it in fact contains (among others) the excluded jar:

```
-classpath ...:/path/to/jar/some/transitive/2.1/some-transitive-2.1.jar:...
```

So my question is: how do I prevent IntelliJ from adding this transitive dependency when it wasn't supposed to?

Just for completeness, here's the conflict I'm talking about (although it's irrelevant to this discussion):

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
  at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.scanClasses(ResourceConfig.java:875)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig._getClasses(ResourceConfig.java:840)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.getClasses(ResourceConfig.java:755)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$RuntimeConfig.<init>(ResourceConfig.java:1171)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$RuntimeConfig.<init>(ResourceConfig.java:1144)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.createRuntimeConfig(ResourceConfig.java:1140)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:299)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:272)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest.<init>(JerseyTest.java:142)
  at com.mypackage.rest.SomeTest.<init>(RestServiceTest.java:19)
```

which is caused by an incompatibility between Jersey and ASM 4.1 (Jersey uses 3.3.1 which has a different group id) which is a transitive dependency pulled from another module.

By the way, I know that IDEA 13 has much better Gradle integration but (a) we have a license for 12 and not upgrading the whole dev team any time soon and (b) IDEA 13 still has a few issues with polyglot Gradle projects (Java/Scala), so it wouldn't fit the bill.

Answer (score 0):

Exclude all transitive dependencies for Maven dependency, but add all required libraries explicitly. With exception of 'some:transitive:2.1', I assume you can run your code without it.

```
group:'some', name:'dependency', version:'1.0' {
    transitive = false
}
// add required transitive libraries here
```

Also, try to run your original code with the latest version of Gradle.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not using Gradle anymore, if anybody can confirm this works I'll accept. Thanks!

Comment: This does not work, I have just checked with Gradle 2.3 and Intellij IDEA 14.1.2 in a similar setup as OP's